# Get Google Calendar events that start and end between two dates

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

As show in the picture I want to get all events that are in the range (start and end) of my 'My Free Time' event. 
In this case there are three events that meet the requirements ('Learning for Exam', 'Homework', 'Coffee').
The 'Running' event start time is out of range of start-end time of 'My Free Time' event.
The 'Cycling' event end time is out of range of start-end time of 'My Free Time' event.

[image]

I am using *Google Calendar API v3*.
I saw the '*timeMax*' and '*timeMin*' parameters in Google Calendar API Reference:
*timeMax - Upper bound (exclusive) for an event's start time to filter by.

timeMin - Lower bound (inclusive) for an event's end time to filter by.*

I make the following call:

```
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => TRUE,
    'timeMin' => '2018-11-27T07:30:00+01:00',
    'timeMax' => '2018-11-27T17:30:00+01:00',
);
```

Where *timeMin* is set to 'My Free Time' event *startTime* & *timeMax* is set to 'My Free Time' event *endTime*.

But in the result there are all the events ('Running', 'Learning for Exam', 'Homework', 'Coffee', 'Cycling'), instead of only 3 events 'Learning for Exam', 'Homework' and 'Coffee'.

The question is: how the *timeMin* & *timeMax* parameters should be set to obtain only the 'Learning for Exam' event ?

The following question is similar:
[Google Calendar Api get events on current week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177931/google-calendar-api-get-events-on-current-week)

but the answers don't fulfill my requirements. My requirements are:
- NOT get the events which start time is BEFORE start-time of the range and the end time is in the range i.e. BEFORE end-time of the range (ex. 'Running' event)
- NOT get the events which end time is AFTER end-time of the range and the start time is in the range i.e. AFTER start-time of the range (ex. 'Cycling' event)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Calendar Api get events on current week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177931/google-calendar-api-get-events-on-current-week)

Comment: Have you tried to add  an optional query parameters `'q' =>  'Learning for Exam',`  ? [link]https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: @Jamie_D It's not the point, I also saw the 'q' parameter, instead 'Learning for Exam' there may be several events.

Answer (score 0):

timeMin--> 2018-11-27T10:30:00+01:00
timeMax--> 2018-11-27T15:30:00+01:00

Comment: 'Learning for exam'  is just an example event that is in the range of 'My Free Time' event. So, there may be several events that are in the range of the 'My Free Time' and your answer is not valid in that case. Please consider how to get all the events that may be in the range of 'My Free Time' event, not how to get only 'Learning for exam' event.

Comment: Facing the same issue. The concept of timeMin and timeMax is confusing enough. I did not see a way to select all meetings that start 30 minutes from now on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you specify the 'timeMin' and 'timeMax' parameters, you will get the events which meets the following condition:
'timeMin' <= 'event end time' < 'timeMax'

In order to get the events that starts and also ends between 'timeMin' and 'timeMax' (as you need), you will have to filter out the returned events which meets the following condition:
'event start time' < 'timeMin'